# Firebase security rules with a relationship

Tags: ember.js, firebase, firebase-security

I have three Ember.js models: user, channel and track. A user can have many channels and tracks belong to a certain channel. They look like this:

```js
// models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  channels: DS.hasMany('channel')
});

// models/channel.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

// models/track.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  channel: DS.belongsTo('channel')
});
```

Now, to create a channel you should be authenticated. To edit/delete I check if that specific channel is in the authenticated user's 'channels' property. Like this:

```js
".write": "(!data.exists() && auth !== null) || (root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/channels').child($channelID).exists())"
```

Is this correct? Seems to work.

To write a track you should be authenticated and the track's `channel` should exist inside the `user/$userid/channels` list.

```js
".write": "root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/channels').child( <<value of the channel property on the track>>  ).exists()"
```

How would I do that?

Comment: The security rule you've written here would work fine, which is why you haven't gotten more bites on this. It's unclear what the actual problem is that you're trying to resolve. Start by ensuring that the channels are stored as keys, e.g. $userid/channels/$channelid/true and not array values or some other format that security rules can't help you read (i.e. it won't do "contains").

Comment: Thank you. Let me try again: I want to allow write on a track if there's no prev data or if the track's channel property has a value equal to one in the authenticated user's channels property.

With JS it'd look something like this: user.channels.contains(track.channel)

I tried this but my syntax is wrong somewhere:

".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/channels').val().contains(data.child('channel').val())"

Comment: There is no contains command, as I noted at the end of my last comment.

Comment: Ok, I must have misunderstood the contains documented here https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables — so in my example /users/userid/channels is an array of values. How do I check if data.child('channel').val() is in that array? I tried "data.child('channel').val() === root.child('users/' + auth.uid + '/channels').val()" which doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you say `data.child('channel')` do you mean the literal key "channel" or an id for a specific channel? The path `auth.uid + '/channels'` presumably contains a list of channel keys to some value (e.g. true) so a specific channel's value is, of course, not going to equal a list of channels. Why would you expect those to be equal? Still extremely murky what you're trying to achieve, what your data looks like, and what you're attempting. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help here.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I really appreciate your help! I meant the id for a specific channel. I understand it wouldn't work but don't know what would work. Please see the question again, I rewrote it to clarify.

Comment: What you have in the question now looks pretty solid.